# How to check if I have shared libraries in ubuntu

Tags: shared-libraries

I did an update in my Ubuntu system and one of old programs running nicely is now giving me an error

> netgen: error while loading shared libraries: libTKBRep.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have seen that once people make sure that they have the library the solution to this problem is often just doing

> sudo ldconfig

However I am very new on this and I an mot sure how to check if I have the library or not.

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem and has been answered many times.

E.g., have a look here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/54736/how-to-check-if-a-library-is-installed